# Sprite Kit - Make SKPhysicsBody with restitution only on sides

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I am trying to create a complex SKPhysicsBody that does not bounce on the top, but does allow bouncing on the sides and bottom. Currently I am creating two nodes. One that has the image of the Sprite and a no restitution PhysicsBody on the top.

My second node matches the first node, but is clear with the same size as the first node It just has a PhysicsBody on the front and bottom and has a restitution. to allow my main character to bounce off the bottom and front.

Here is the code for my current setup:

```
    //This is the top part.
- (void)nodePhysicsBodySetup:(SKSpriteNode *)node
{
    CGPoint topStart = CGPointMake(0, node.size.height);
    CGPoint topEnd = CGPointMake(node.size.width, node.size.height);
    SKPhysicsBody *topEdge = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:topStart toPoint:topEnd];
    node.physicsBody = topEdge;
    //[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[topEdge, frontEdge, bottomEdge]]
    //node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node.frame.size];
    node.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    node.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
    node.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = groundCategory;
    node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = mainHeroCategory;
    node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = mainHeroCategory;
}
//This is the bottom physicsbody that matches up with the image of the main node.
- (void)bottomNodePhysicsBodySetup:(SKSpriteNode *)node
{
    CGPoint topStart = CGPointMake(0, node.size.height);
    CGPoint frontEnd = CGPointMake(0,0);
    CGPoint bottomEnd = CGPointMake(node.size.width,0);
    SKPhysicsBody *frontEdge = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:topStart toPoint:frontEnd];
    SKPhysicsBody *bottomEdge = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:frontEnd toPoint:bottomEnd];
    bottomNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[frontEdge, bottomEdge]];
    bottomNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    bottomNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    bottomNode.physicsBody.restitution = 0.5;
    bottomNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = otherCategory;
    bottomNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = mainHeroCategory;
    bottomNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = mainHeroCategory;
}
```

Picture as screenshots are under NDA:
[image]

Currently, the Green PhysicsBody is attached to the node, and the red PhysicsBody is attached to a transparent second node with the same position as the first node.

This does not really work. My main character (mainHeroCategory) gets stuck sometimes on the node corner where the PhysicsBody with restitution and the one without meet. What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do this using only one physics body and look at the contact delegate methods to determine where the contact occurred and what the normal vector is (that information is in the SKPhysicsContact object passed in the delegate method).

Once I got that information I would apply an impulse to the mainHeroCategory object, or not, depending on where the contact occurred.

Comment: I am having trouble detecting where on the physics body it was hit. What method are you recommending? This seems like a good way to go.

Comment: If you implement the SKPhysicsContactDelegate the method didBeginContact gives you an SKPhysicsContact object.  That object https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContact/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/SKPhysicsContact gives you the information about where the contact occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you join the physics bodies with an [SKPhysicsJointFixed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJointFixed_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/SKPhysicsJointFixed) or by constraining the bodies with an [SKConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKConstraint/distance:toNode:) or two. SpriteKit only uses the shape when merging two or more bodies with `bodyWithBodies`. From the docs...

> The properties on the children, such as mass or friction, are ignored.
>   Only the shapes of the child bodies are used.

The `restitution` property is ignored.

Comment: The bottom node is not added as a child to the top. It is just the same size and placed so that it fits the top node.

Comment: From the commented code in your question, it looks like you considered using `bodyWithBodies` to connect the top and bottom. In that case, the children are physics bodies. How are you connecting the top to the bottom?

Comment: Oh I see the confusion. I am not currently connecting them, I just set them up so they meet. One physicsbody covers the top of the node, the second nodes physicsbody lines up with the first nodes top physicsbody. I wish I could post a picture but it is under NDA. Ill try to create it again in a new project.

Comment: Can you post a sketch of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Or provide additional details in your question.

Comment: I added a picture to help.

Comment: You can create two physics bodies: one on the top (a line with restitution = 0) and one on the bottom (a rectangle with non-zero restitution). You can then join the two bodies with a fixed physics joint to create a composite body that has the appropriate restitution properties.

Comment: Do I still need to have two different Nodes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66611/discussion-between-siriss-and-0x141e).